# (Python) How to fit ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
target= data.satisfaction
features = data.evaluation
target_train,target_test,features_train,features_test=train_test_split(
target,features,test_size=0.25)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
model.fit(features_train,target_train)
model.score(features_train,target_train)*100
model.score(features_test,target_test)*100
```

The problem is :

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>   array=[0.57 0.86 0.62 ... 0.99 0.96 0.8 ].
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Have you tried following the advice from the error?

Comment: Have you tried to reshape your arrays' features and target?

Comment: try this before train-test split features = features.reshape(-1,1)

Comment: I try to use reshape. but the console showing AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: @GaleYan _I try to use reshape. but the console showing AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'_ Alright, what do/don't you understand from that error? Have you tried converting to Series to a NumPy array?

Comment: i use 'target = np.reshape(-1,1)
features = np.reshape(-1,1)'. but the result is "ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.25 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters."